# Is it possible to add custom fields to gridfs using mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Can I add my fields to gridfs using C#. For example I have company collection :

```
[
 { 
  companyid:
...
 },
]
```

I want to store my companyid in gridfs file chunks or file reference I don't want to use filename field.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53956a7d5f26f52e0c19c5b9"),
    "filename" : "f123db3d16a2d1417c1b67e133373549a729.xsl",
    "length" : NumberLong(15525),
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-06-09T08:04:13.093Z"),
    "md5" : "3c47805c7225764cdb15826dfc8c42cb",
    "CompanyId":""(my company collection id)
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. it is possible.
You can store data in gridfs metadata.

For example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53956a7d5f26f52e0c19c5b9"),
    "filename" : "f123db3d16a2d1417c1b67e133373549a729.xsl",
    "length" : NumberLong(15525),
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-06-09T08:04:13.093Z"),
    "md5" : "3c47805c7225764cdb15826dfc8c42cb",
    metadata: null
}
```

You should be able to add it to metadata just fine. Just make sure you add an index on the metadata field that you want to query on:

```
db.colName.ensureIndex( { 'metadata.CompanyId' : 1 } );
```

I hope that supports your question.